# Como "matar" uma classe no VBA - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu tenho um código que chama um Private sub que por sua vez apaga os dados de uma planilha. Se eu fizer o mesmo procedimento sem fechar o formulário ele dá erro na hora de apagar os dados, porém se eu crio um novo sub com outro nome e o mesmo código ele roda normalmente duas vezes. Queria saber se existe algum método como o dispose para objetos em outras linguagens, algo que mate a sub após rodar tudo dentro dela para poder rodar novamente.

Comment: Boa tarde, acredito que tentar resolver o problema que ocorre seria o caminho mais fácil e mais correto para o seu propósito. Posta a parte de código desta Sub para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: `Sub` não é um módulo de classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um código que acabei de criar para outro usuário. Convertendo datas.

De acordo com o que mencionou acima, se entendi bem você quer para o script ao executar tal procedimento, certo? Se positivo experimente colocar o comando `Exit Sub` (sem aspas) no local onde você quer parar o código. Segue modelo abaixo.

Procure esta observação no script abaixo para entender melhor: `<----- este é o código que faz parar o script.`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Dim CData As Date
Dim CData2 As Date


Sub DataCompra1()
    {'--- FORMATANDO DATA MOD 01}

    [C8].Select
    CData = [C8].Value

    If CData = "0" Then
        MsgBox "INFORME A DATA"
        'Exit Sub '--- ESTA FUNÇÃO PARA O SCRIPT, CASO QUEIRA UTILIZAR DESCOMENTE A LINHA
    Else

        ActiveCell.Value = ""
        Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CData
        Exit Sub                                 '<----- ESTE É O CÓDIGO QUE FAZ PARAR O SCRIPT.
        MsgBox CData

    End If

End Sub

Sub DataCompra2()
    {'--- FORMATANDO DATA MOD 02}

    Dim CData As Date
    Dim CHora As Date

    dt = [C8].Value
    CData = Format(dt)
    CHora = Format(Now)

    [E8].Value = CData
    [E9].Value = CHora

End Sub

Sub LimparData()

    [C8].Value = ""
    [E8].Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: é isto! muito obrigado!!!!